# DateTimeZone class possibly not installed?

Tags: php

I've got a server that has PHP 5.3.3 installed.  I know the PHP manual says that DateTimeZone requires 5.2 or greater, so I should be good, but instead I'm getting an error:

Warning: require_once(datetimezone.php): failed to open stream: in /public_html/admin/index.php on line 12 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'datetimezone.php'

I'm guessing since I have an autoload function set up (around line 12 in index.php), that it's not finding the DateTimeZone class, then trying to autoload the appropriately named file and failing.

```
function __autoload($class) {
    $path = strtolower(str_replace('_', '/', $class));
    require_once "$path.php";
}
```

How do I install/check that DateTimeZone is installed?

Comment: You're error has nothing to do with DateTimeZone(). DateTimeZone() is always enabled and doesn't need to be required. You just have an error including one of your files is all. Make sure the file exists ans your path is correct.

Comment: @John Conde: it's an autoload which shouldn't run for a built-in class at first place.

Comment: @Kai: is your code in `index.php` inside a namespace?

Comment: No, it is not in a namespace.

Comment: @Kai: how exactly you're instantiating `DateTimeZone` class?

Comment: @John Conde: exactly *what*? It's not OP who requires the file explicitly. It's php that for some reason cannot instantiate `DateTimeZone` thus runs autoload. And that's what OP asked about.

Comment: So I'm not exactly sure where it's getting hung up on DateTimeZone because it's going to the autoload function when it dies, but I believe the problem instantiation is:  `$toTimezone = new DateTimeZone($toTimezone);
  $fromTimezone =  new DateTimeZone('UTC');
  $time = new DateTime($time, $fromTimezone);
  $time->setTimeZone($toTimezone);
  return $time->format($format);`

Comment: @Kai: It works fine for `PHP >= 5.2` http://3v4l.org/lNa8J#tabs Could you create a file that only contains these lines and nothing else?

Comment: I just verified that skipping those lines, the error no longer appears.

Comment: I should also note that the code runs fine, on a different server.

Comment: @Kai: `phpinfo()` and double check the php version.

Comment: Ah, yeah, it is php 5.1, after all.  I got the two server windows mixed up I guess.  =(  Thanks all for the help.